# Function which takes an array and function, calls function with the array mapped to each elements .value property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function which takes two parameters: an array of objects with a key called value; and a function which should recieve the array mapped to the .value property. I have already achieved this without the array and it's just one object, which covers certain scenarios, but i also want to be able to support multiple values.

So currently my code looks like this:

```js
class A<T> {
    constructor(public value: T) {}
}

function b<T, U>(inputs: A<U>, valueFn: (inputs: U) => T) {
    const value = valueFn(inputs.value) // value is T, as expected
}

let b0 = b(new A(1), a0 => a0) // a0 is of type number, as expected
```

But I also want to be able to do this:

```js
let b1 = b([new A(1), new A(true)], ([a0, a1]) => console.log(a0, a1)) // a0 should be number, a1 should be boolean
```

I don't know how to approach this and I can't find anything online.

Comment: I have a feeling that this question could be much simpler and easier to understand. Currently I am having trouble understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: @starikcetin I'm trying to do the thing in the second snippet. The type for the array is [A<number>, A<boolean>] and the first parameter of the second argument should be inferred as [number, boolean]

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your generic parameter `U` to extend `A<any>` and declare `inputs: U[]` which forces you to always pass an array. Then you can extract the generic argument using [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html?#inferring-within-conditional-types) and return an array of that. This will give you a union type `number` | `boolean`. If you want specifically wanted `[number, boolean]` I think you'd have to work with `const` values.

```
class A<T> {
  constructor(public value: T) {}
}

function b<T, U extends A<any>>(
  inputs: U[],
  valueFn: (inputs: U extends A<infer V> ? V[] : never) => T
) {
  const value = valueFn(inputs[0].value); // value is T, as expected
}

let b0 = b([new A(1)], a0 => a0); // a0 is of type number, as expected
let b1 = b(
  [new A(1), new A(true)],
  (
    [a0, a1] // a0 and a1 of type number | boolean
  ) => console.log(a0, a1)
);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVAfNA3gWAFDWsA9gHYQAuATgK7An5kAUADhQEYgCWw0AbmCBQKYAuaIgCU6AL7YpWbADMKhamyLRmSADTQAqtH4APEv0IATGAjCEAnsmR1suNoSYkIw7QG0AuhofdeAgBihMJ0Ti5uOnqGxmZw8E5y-GTQAGqoAPxp3tDChPxcyeIAvKiI2OKYOHhEpP58-NDF9UGEYc4Urh4ADF4AdDwNogDc0AD0Yy2NbDCIWpDRDPzU-CbS2Ngg-CRq3U1qdB75AO5wdACMoj7QYHulN90j45O30DPQ%20HLQJFZL0IQUAC2zGS8xgBiWKzWWC2O2Y532zHs1SO-FOsAuoi0JzO5AEV181WRuFwHlu83OXmeDxuphuCM%2031%20jQBwOS0AAPmp8PgtpY-CVUARiLz%20H0QPgAOZ0cn00QVYZAA)